# Tensorflow Linear model error

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, linear-regression

I am new to the tensorflow environment and I wrote this piece of code in Jupyter-notebook and the loss function is increasing rapidly.

I have used gradient descent as optimizer and learning rate of `0.05`.
If learning rate is changed to `0.0000005` then the loss is around `101.82`

### ------------------------------------------------------------------

I dont know what to do.

```
 import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf

from __future__ import division

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

#x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

y  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

b = tf.Variable([1.0], tf.float32)

w1 = tf.Variable([1.0], tf.float32)

init = tf.Session()

​

lin_mod = w1 * x + b

squared_delta = tf.square(lin_mod - y)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_delta)

my_opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05)

train = my_opt.minimize(loss)

x_train = [

237,

    229.5,

    232.45,

    207.4,

    205.65,

    207.3,

    ]

    ]

    y_train = [237,

    230,

    233,

    207.2,

    208.9,

    207.5,

 ]

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess.run(init)

for i in range(100):

    print(sess.run(train, {x:x_train, y:y_train}))

    print(sess.run(loss, {x:x_train, y:y_train}))

None
209335760000.0
None
8.30988e+21
None
3.298725e+32
None
inf
Non
```

Comment: "I don't know, what to do" is not really a question. So what is your question? Please read also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can improve here, but you're mostly on the right track by reducing the learning rate. As you noticed 0.5 is too large of a learning rate. Consider that you're starting your weights all at 1.0 (an issue I'll get to in a moment) I guess the initial predictions are 2.0 as well and your error is around `200^2` per sample. That will produce one heck of a large gradient.

So the first issue is numerical stability of your labels. It's generally a good idea to keep your labels as reasonably small numbers. If the network needs to predict large values the weights need to be large and that causes wild swings in the predictions that aren't good for learning. You can scale all your labels down by say dividing them all by 200, then rescaling them back up after the prediction is made.

Next you are initializing your weights to a constant, the same constant, here's an article that talks about why you shouldn't do that:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/danger-of-setting-all-initial-weights-to-zero-in-backpropagation

Set your weights to a random initial value. For example, taken from the tensorflow docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/programmers_guide/variables):

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 200], stddev=0.35), name="weights")
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([200]), name="biases")
```

Last note, you can condense these lines:

```
for i in range(100):
  print(sess.run(train, {x:x_train, y:y_train}))
  print(sess.run(loss, {x:x_train, y:y_train}))
```

Into this:

```
for i in range(100):
  print(sess.run([train, loss], {x:x_train, y:y_train}))
```

That won't affect your results, but you don't need to run the forward computation twice.